# how make (make: auth) Laravel 6 for api without installing ui

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-6

I am testing laravel 6 creating an api.

The command `make:auth` has been deleted.

I have to install laravel/ui although I am creating an api?

Comment: What do you mean that `make:auth` has been deleted? When you try the command do you get an error message?

Comment: @RyanNerd It was moved  into a separate *laravel/ui* package with version 6. We have to use `ui:auth` now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/)? It's Laravel's library for micro-services and APIs.

Otherwise, it does look like you'll need to install `laravel/ui` as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#included-routing). Then you could auto-generate auth routes and views:

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try Lumen as it fits more than I need.

Comment: This should be not the correct answer because that solution does not remove the views during the auth instalation